# Turning off Events and Firing the same ones back up again - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery's new On() and Off(). When an event is turned off, can it be turned back on again? If so, does anyone have a simple example they can show me? I've looked around but can't seem to grasp what is out there on the internet. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

**Q. When an event is turned off, can it be turned back on again?**

Don't think of `.on()` and `.off()` as turning the events on and off. `.on()` assigns a function that you provide to handle an event, so:

```
$("someselector").on("click", function() { });
// is equivalent to
$("someselector").click(function() { });
```

That is, when a click occurs on the element in question the function you specified will be called.

The `.off()` method removes the handler you previously assigned using either `.on()` *or* `.click()` - it doesn't temporarily disable the event or the event handler. So after calling `.off()` your click handler function will not be called again unless you rebind it with `.on()` or `.click()`. You'll notice in the fiddle you provided in a comment that after you've called `.off()` that element never responds to clicks again because you never bind another handler back to it - calling `.on()` with no parameters doesn't do anything.

In my opinion the simplest way to do what you are asking about is what jfriend00 showed, that is, use a boolean variable to decide whether to do anything when the event occurs. The function will be called on *every* click, but if some other part of your code has set that boolean then the function will return without doing anything.

Comment: Great explanation @nnnnnn!  I am understanding it more now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to suspend an event handler, you can either remove it with `.off()` and then assign it again from scratch with `.on()` or you can add a flag to the event handler that tells your code to skip actually handling it whenever you set that flag.

```
var buttonOff = true;
$('.fun').on('click', '.button', function() {
    if (buttonOff) return(false);
    // normal button handling code here
});
```

Comment: Hey @jsfriend00 - I'm trying to do something like this. Am I way off?  http://jsfiddle.net/WLU2m/

Comment: @Joe, you need to read the jQuery doc for `.on()` and `.off()`.  What you're trying to do in your jsFiddle will not work.  That's not how either `.on()` or `.off()` work.

Answer (score 0):

The `off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`. You have to rebind the event handlers if you want them back.